# How to set value of a FormView textbox to the value of a HiddenField in an ASP.net c# WebForms Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on an asp.net c# WebForms application.  The form has two controls, a GridView and a FormView.  The FormView is populated when a row is selected in the GridView.  This all works as expected.  The problem is that I need the value of the Id field from the GridView to be the value of a field in the FormView's InsertItemTemplate.  The following passes the Id of the GridView (venId) to the HiddenField on SelectedIndexChanged:

```
protected void rg_vendors_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridDataItem item in rg_vendors.Items)
        {
            hdn_ven_id.Value = item["venId"].Text;
        }
    }
```

Next I would like to set the value of the venIdFk field in the FormViewto be equal to the value of hdn_ven_id when inserting the FormView data into the database.  I don't know how to get this done, but here is an idea of what I need:

```
protected void fv_vc_ItemInsert(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        (TextBox)fv_vc.FindControl("venIdFk") = hdn_ven_id.Value;
    }
```

The formview is fv_vc
The gridview is rg_vendors
The hidden field is hdn_ven_id
This is an asp.net c# webforms application 
I am using VS2013

Please let me know if the code of the FormView and GridView are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer at the following thread ... http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/389192/Access-and-Set-Value-in-TextBox-inside-FormView-Control-in-ASPNet/ .